# How To Assign Permenant Public IP to a VM in Azure, So Even If it Shuts Down and Boots Back Up It Does Not Lose Its IP?

Tags: command-line-interface, azure, ip-address

I have read the Azure documentation which explains how to allocate a reserved IP, etc. Exactly what command do I need to run from Azure command prompt to do this to an existing VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an Instance Level IP to an existing VM using:

`Get-AzureVM -ServiceName FTPService -Name $FTPInstance | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName $FTPIP | Update-AzureVM`

The full page of information for Instance Level IPs is here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

Comment: It would be helpful if you defined $FTPInstance even if you only set it as a sample Name

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign reserved IP to existing VM. You must capture VM and provision it with reserved IP.